# What's the difference between the durable and delivery_mode for an exchange?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, kombu

I'm working on the configuration for some RabbitMQ queues and exchanges configured via Celery and Kombu.

The exchange object provided by Kombu can accept two specific options that overlap in the way I understand them:

- `durable`
- `delivery_mode`

What would be the result if I set these values:

- `durable = True` and `delivery_mode = 1` (transient) ?
- `durable = False` and `delivery_mode = 2` (persistent) ?

Answer (score 1):

'durable' means that the exchange will survive a RabbitMQ restart.  From the Kombu documentation:

> Durable exchanges remain active when a server restarts. Non-durable exchanges (transient exchanges) are purged when a server restarts. Default is True.

I'm not an expert in Kombu, so I am not sure the best practice there for creating exchanges and queues and binding them.  In RabbitMQ, messages are published to an exchange with a routing key.  RabbitMQ checks which queue or queues are bound to that exchange with that routing key and sends messages to that queue(s).  The exchange and queue each can have the property of durable or not.

delivery_mode is applied to messages stored in a queue.

Reasonable designs are (a) to have both the queue and the messages survive a RabbitMQ restart, (b) queue is durable and messages are deleted on restart, and (c) both queue and its messages are deleted on restart.  The case you propose where messages survive restart but queue does not will result in messages not actually surviving restart.